# Broken Package, after force installation of libstd++ ubuntu 16.04.01

Tags: apt, package-management

I have upgraded my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to 16.04.01 LTS. After upgradation, it's giving me error of "relocation error" from libstdc++ as GLIBC_XX_3.4.21 is missing. So, i downloaded the libstdc++ package from the internet and forcefully installed it using, `dpkg`

Now I am getting the below error message on my screen on running apt-get.

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these: The
following packages have unmet dependencies:  libstdc++6 : Depends:
gcc-6-base (= 6.2.0-1) but 6.1.1-3ubuntu11~14.04.1 is to be installed

            Breaks: libboost-date-time1.54.0 but 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
            Breaks: libkolabxml1 (<= 1.1.0-3) but 1.0.1-0ubuntu3 is to be installed
            Breaks: schroot (<= 1.6.10-1+b1) but 1.6.10-1ubuntu3 is to be installed
            Breaks: libstdc++6:i386 (!= 6.2.0-1) but 6.1.1-3ubuntu11~14.04.1 is to be installed  libstdc++6:i386 : Breaks: libstdc++6 (!= 6.1.1-3ubuntu11~14.04.1) but 6.2.0-1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I have already tried forced installation by running apt-get -f install but it didn't work out. Could someone please help me, how can I downgrade the package without breaking anything.

The output for apt -f install:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed. The following packages have unmet dependencies: 

libstdc++6 : Depends: gcc-6-base (= 6.1.1-11) but 6.1.1-3ubuntu11~14.04.1 is installed
            Breaks: libboost-date-time1.54.0 but 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 is installed
            Breaks: libkolabxml1 (<= 1.1.0-3) but 1.0.1-0ubuntu3 is installed
            Breaks: schroot (<= 1.6.10-1+b1) but 1.6.10-1ubuntu3 is installed
            Breaks: libstdc++6:i386 (!= 6.1.1-11) but 6.1.1-3ubuntu11~14.04.1 is installed  libstdc++6:i386 : Breaks: libstdc++6 (!= 6.1.1-3ubuntu11~14.04.1) but 6.1.1-11 is installed E:
Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages. 
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the output of `apt -f install`?

Comment: Edited my question, and provided the output for apt -f install.

Comment: I am ready to install the missing dependencies manually, but I am not able to understand their meaning. What does depends, breaks here represents. And what I need to install here.

Comment: Do you have any PPAs/custom repos active on your device?

Comment: No, I haven't added any extra PPAs.

Comment: What "libstdc++ package from the internet" did you force install, exactly?

Comment: this one : /usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6.0.22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the release of new packages in distribution that are dependent to upgrade, everything worked out with `sudo apt -f install`. Each dependencies are fixed.